# MS Access Union Query with group by and criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have the following query and need to do a union with another table which has the exact same fields.  The criteria, however, could span information in both tables.

Any ideas on how to do the union with the group by and criteria?

```
SELECT sporderpipeline.coordinator, 
       sporderpipeline.[update date], 
       Count(sporderpipeline.loan_number) AS CountOfLoan_Number, 
       sporderpipeline.[data source] 
FROM   sporderpipeline 
GROUP  BY sporderpipeline.coordinator, 
          sporderpipeline.[update date], 
          sporderpipeline.status, 
          sporderpipeline.[data source] 
HAVING ( ( ( sporderpipeline.[update date] ) BETWEEN #8/23/2015# AND #8/24/2015# 
         ) 
         AND ( ( sporderpipeline.status ) IS NOT NULL ) );
```

Comment: Have you tried any of *your* ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a `HAVING` clause for those criteria - `HAVING` is only necessary for criteria based on aggregate functions such as COUNT or SUM.

The simplest way to write your UNION query is as follows:

```
SELECT [sporderpipeline].[coordinator], 
       [sporderpipeline].[update date], 
       Count([sporderpipeline].[loan_number]) AS CountOfLoan_Number, 
       [sporderpipeline].[data source] 
FROM   sporderpipeline 
WHERE  [update date] BETWEEN #8/23/2015# AND #8/24/2015# 
       AND status IS NOT NULL 
GROUP  BY [sporderpipeline].[coordinator], 
          [sporderpipeline].[update date], 
          [sporderpipeline].[status], 
          [sporderpipeline].[data source] 
UNION 
SELECT [sporderpipeline].[coordinator], 
       [sporderpipeline].[update date], 
       Count([sporderpipeline].[loan_number]) AS CountOfLoan_Number, 
       [sporderpipeline].[data source] 
FROM   sporderpipeline 
WHERE  [update date] BETWEEN #8/23/2015# AND #8/24/2015# 
       AND status IS NOT NULL 
GROUP  BY [sporderpipeline].[coordinator], 
          [sporderpipeline].[update date], 
          [sporderpipeline].[status], 
          [sporderpipeline].[data source]
```

Having said that, it would also work with a HAVING clause, which is not incompatible with a UNION.

Comment: You'll need to sprinkle in a few more `[tablename].` references for this to work.

Comment: Lol yeah well I was just copying from the question!

Answer (score 0):

Create the companion query.  We'll call it `MyQuery_Second`.

`SELECT * FROM MyQuery_First UNION SELECT * FROM MyQuery_Second;`

... or possibly even ...

`MyQuery_First UNION MyQuery_Second;`

It should just work.